# Is there any good reason to catch exceptions in unittest transactions?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

The unittest module is extremely good to detect problems in code.
I understand the idea of isolating and testing parts of code with assertions:

`self.assertEqual(web_page_view.func, web_page_url)`

But besides these assertions you also might have some logic before it, in the same test method, that could have problems.

I am wondering if manual exception handling is something to take in account ever inside methods of a TestCase subclass.

Because if I wrap a block in a try-catch, if something fails, the test returns OK and does not fail:

```
    def test_simulate_requests(self):
        """
        Simulate requests to a url
        """
        try:
           response = self.client.get('/adress/of/page/')
           self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        except Exception as e:
            print("error: ", e)
```

Should exception handling be always avoided in such tests?

Comment: The usual practice is to use `assertRaises` assertion when you're expecting some exception to be raised. On other cases, you should treat them as regular test and not catch any exception yourself manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First part of answer:

As you correctly say, there needs to be some logic before the actual test.  The code belonging to a unit-test can be clustered into four parts (I use Meszaros' terminology in the following): setup, exercise, verify, teardown.  Often the code of a test case is structured such that the code for the four parts are cleanly separated and come in that precise order - this is called the four phase test pattern.

The exercise phase is the heart of the test, where the functionality is executed that shall be checked in the test.  The setup ensures that this happens in a well defined context.  So, what you have described is in this terminology the situation that during setup something fails.  Which means, that the preconditions are not met which are required for a meaningful execution of the functionality that is to be tested.

This is a common situation and it means that you in fact need to be able to distinguish three outcomes of a test: A test can pass successfully, it can fail, or it can just be meaningless.

Fortunately, there is an answer for this in python: You can skip tests, and if a test is skipped this is recorded, but neither as a failure nor as a success.  Skipping of tests would probably a better way to handle the situation that you have shown in your example.  Here is a small code piece that demonstrates one way of skipping tests:

```
import unittest
class TestException(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_skipTest_shallSkip(self):
      self.skipTest("Skipped because skipping shall be demonstrated.")
```

Second part of answer:

Your test seems to have some non-deterministic elements.  The `self.client.get` can throw exceptions (but only sometimes - sometimes it doesn't).  This means you do not have the context during the test execution under control.  In unit-testing this is a situation you should try to avoid.  Your tests should have a deterministic behavior.

One typical way to achieve this is to isolate your code from the components that are responsible for the nondeterminism and during testing replace these components by mocks.  The behaviour of the mocks is under full control of the test code.  Thus, if your code uses some component for network accesses, you would mock that component.  Then, in some test cases you can instruct the mock to simulate a successful network communication to see how your component handles this, and in other tests you instruct the mock to simulate a network failure to see how your component copes with this situation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two "bad" states of a test: Failure (when one of the assertions fails) and Error (when the test itself fails - your case).

First of all, it goes without saying that it's better to build your test in such a way that it reaches its assertions.

If you need to assert some tested code raises an exception, you should use `with self.assertRaises(ExpectedError)`

If some code inside the test raises an exception - it's better to know it from 'Error' result than seeing 'OK all tests have passed'

If your test logic really assumes that something can fail in the test itself and it is normal behaviour - probably the test is wrong. May be you should use mocks (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) to imitate an api call or something else.

In your case, even if the test fails, you catch it with bare except and say "Ok, continue". Anyway the implementation is wrong.

Finally: no, there shouldn't be except in your test cases

P.S. it's better to call your test functions with test_what_you_want_to_test_name, in this case probably test_successful_request would be ok.